# Set form element based on mobile viewport

Tags: html, css, viewport

What is the best way to add form elements based on viewport?

Say I have the following form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="mobile" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Is there a way to set the value of the `mobile` input 1 if the viewport is less than a set viewport width?

Would I have to do this in javascript or is there a way to do this via CSS?

Comment: Yes you would need JavaScript. CSS can not alter the value of an input.

Comment: Thanks - I was wondering if there was a way to display: none / remove the element based on viewport

Comment: You can _hide_ an element using CSS media queries but you can not _remove_ an element entirely. Though this is already a hidden input so you aren't going to achieve anything by hiding it with CSS. It would still be submitted with your form.

Comment: It would be simple to update the value with JS: https://jsfiddle.net/50vdy91q/2/

Comment: Thanks - if you add that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Why not use media queries and display none? - display none inputs don't get submitted (I think)